# QGIS Raster Calculator - keep orginal values instead of 1s and 0s?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I have a crop data raster layer in QGIS with one band with values from 10 to 230.

I have written an expression in the Raster Calculator to keep only a number of values (e.g. when = 145 OR when = to 146, etc..

This works but the resulting layer has 0 values for areas that did not satisfy the expression and 1's for areas that did.  As a result, I appear to have lost the original raster values which indicate crop types.

Am I doing this wrong or maybe there's another way to filter that will keep my original values?

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear. If you have 145, you want to get 145. for 146 -> 146. But what values do you want to have for 10, 50, 100 etc.?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear...those other values I'm not interested in can be 0.  So for example:

10--->0
20-->0
140-->140
145--->145
190--->0
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use QGIS 3.22 or later, you have the new conditional `if` in raster calculator:

```
IF ("RASTER@1" >= 145 AND "RASTER@1" <= 146, "RASTER@1", 0)
```

For older versions, use:

```
("RASTER@1" >= 145 and "RASTER@1" <= 146) * "N45E006@1"
```

I would not advice using something like `"RASTER@1" = 145 or "RASTER@1" = 146`: probably pixel values will not match exactly integers (145.00, 146.00), but be rather like 145.7 and using this expression, it will not find anything.

Comment: Thanks @Babel I'll try that.

SO would that keep those values as 145 or 146 and all other values set to 0?

Comment: It keeps all values from 145 to 146 and sets all others to 0

Comment: Thanks @Babel this worked perfectly!