Merge to raster layers
I'm not new to GIS, but quite new to working with raster data.
I'm working with QGIS and having trouble to merge to raster layers.
I want layer A with all its values, exept where layer B has values, then those shall be used.
Can someone explain me on how to handle this?
I tried this and other equations..
if ("k_mmh_rueckegasse_911@1" > 0,"k_mmh_rueckegasse_911@1","k_mmh@1")


When using raster calculator, it is a bit tricky if you have different extents (solution: Virtual Raster) and NoData values resulting from this (solution: Fill NoData values). See here how to solve this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456134/88814 For If-conditions in raster calculator, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414826/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420699/88814

See here for a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/411404/88814
